# Cannot run pip due to a circular import in pip itself

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I created a new virtual environment, and installed a package (particularly, `cvxpy`). I ran some tests and it worked fine. Then, for no apparent reason, I started getting errors when running `pip`:

```
(.venv39a) PS D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy> python -m pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy\.venv39a\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy\.venv39a\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy\.venv39a\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.metadata import get_default_environment
  File "D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy\.venv39a\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>    from .base import (BaseDistribution, BaseEnvironment, FilesystemWheel,
  File "D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy\.venv39a\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\base.py", line 22, in <module>   
    from pip._vendor.packaging.requirements import Requirement
  File "D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy\.venv39a\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pyparsing import Combine
  File "D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy\.venv39a\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing\__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    from .common import _builtin_exprs as common_builtin_exprs
  File "D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy\.venv39a\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing\common.py", line 5, in <module>   
    from .helpers import any_close_tag, any_open_tag, delimited_list
  File "D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy\.venv39a\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing\helpers.py", line 5, in <module>  
    from . import __diag__
ImportError: cannot import name '__diag__' from partially initialized module 'pip._vendor.pyparsing' (most likely due to a circular import) (D:\Dropbox\ariel-algorithms\cvxpy\.venv39a\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing\__init__.py)
```

It says there is a circular import in `pip` itself - how can this be?

I tried to remove the virtual environment and re-install everything, but after some time, it happened again. How can I debug this strange circular import, in `pip` itself?

Comment: Do you encounter the same problem if you create the virtual environment *not* within your Dropbox folder?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I tried again outside dropbox, and so far it works fine - but why should it matter?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I assume it has something to do with the fact that Dropbox - being a file sync service - holds itself free to read and write arbitrary files within that directory at any time? Possibly including ones that `pip` wants to access or replace? I think you really have a Dropbox tech support question, which is off topic here.